# Image update in memory won't reflect in react native image component

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm making an android app using react native. The app uses java/native code for image processing.

The app has an image compononent which on click calls a java function that creates an image and saves it to the internal storage and returns the URI to it.
(the result image may differ)

Sample code is:

```
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(imgPath);
    resultMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
    finishCallback.invoke(false);
    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
} finally {
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        finishCallback.invoke(false);
        Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}

finishCallback.invoke(true,imgPath.toURI().toString());
```

The recieving side should update the image component to show the saved image.

When I run this for the first time it works fine but then when I run it again the component is not being updated even though the image in the storage has changed.

In order to update the view I need to close the app and restart it telling it to show what is saved in the storage and then it shows the change.

- This only happens if the returning URI has already been used before although I've checked and made sure the old image is deleted and there is a new one.

The recieving side looks like so:

(JniActivity.fillDoor is the java functiong responsible for updating the image in the storage)

```
  onSelectFillImage = (source) => {
  JniActivity.fillDoor(
  this.state.doorImageSource.uri,
  source.uri,
  (isDone, picURI) => {
    Alert.alert("is done: " + isDone);
    if (isDone) {

      const fixed = picURI

      const source1 = { uri: fixed };

      this.setState({
        filledDoorImageSource: source1
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After invastigating this issue turns out the problem was the componnent caches the image.

As long as you are using the same URI the component will not turn to the server to update the image and would rather use the cached information.

Althougth there are ways to tell the component to not cache the image from my understanding there is no way to gurantee for 100% that the component will not cache dispite your best afforts.

The quickest solution would be to add a large random number to the image name which would make sure the URI will never repeat (while making sure of course you delete all previous no longer needed data).

Example code:

```
String ImageName += Integer.toString(Math.round(Math.random()*1000000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

So like you said the problem is that the url is the same even though the image itself has changed. React native components and pure components have a low level check for updates. That means that they will check if the new prop has the same value as the old one and in your case since the url doesn't change it is getting the same value and will decide that it does not need to update. What you could do as a solution is that along with the url also have a flag in your state for whether or not the image should rerender ( something like shouldReload: boolean) and everytime your JAVA function returns a url toggle that flag to make your image rerender.

Comment: a setState function is called when the uri gets changed, is'nt that enough? Now I also added a key property to my Image component with the uri value, if that helps I also tried to change the uri to null before the changes to make sure it refreshes

Comment: It would be if the uri itself changes, but since the uri is the same but the image at that location has changed (react native cannot verify this) the component will not update

Comment: ok, I tried this.forceUpdate() and it didn't work.. so I tried this: change the uri to another image, and the view updates and shows it but when switching back to the "not updated" URI it shows the not updated image again even though I'm absolutly sure it has been updated in the memory.

Comment: It is not a render issue, again as Iv'e said even after force changing the image to something else (which works) and then back to the URI, It shows the old image, the image doesnt even exists in the memory any more, I dont understand where does it take it from.                                                       If I close the app and open and only tell it to show the uri it shows the updated image

Answer (score 0):

You can ask react to render new image by adding random string in url as a param. If param changes, it will re render new image instead of cached one.

Here is how I did it,

```
file://${store.root.registerImagePath}/${member.userId}.jpg?time=${new Date()}
```